# jQuery cookie set up issue

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am trying to set up a cookie with jQuery, however it's not showing the cookie at all.
Can somebody explain me where I am doing wrong please? http://jsfiddle.net/RVFX4/1/

I have this set up in my index.html:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.cookie("test", 1, {
           expires : 10,           

           path    : '/',          

           domain  : 'jquery.com',  


           secure  : true  

        });

    });
```

I am supposed to get a cookie named test with a value of 1 right?

Comment: There's something wrong with the options you're using.  Not sure what, but if you remove everything except `expires` then it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the comments in the fiddle:

```
path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                        //(default: path of page that created the cookie).

domain  : 'jquery.com',  //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                        //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

secure  : true          //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                        //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                        //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
```

Obviously the domain is not jquery.com, and the path is not the root either (because the page with the actual code is hosted in a subdomain). And finally the protocol is plain http so the `secure: true` requirement prevents the cookie from being created.

If you remove those lines it works in jsfiddle, and it should work if the parameters are given correctly in other domains. You shouldn't need to give them at all unless there's a specific reason to do so.

Comment: even by just using ' expires : 10' on my local it still doesn't set the cookie but it does work in fiddle following your suggestions...

Comment: Do you have a server set up on your computer? You can't set cookies in the local filesystem (`file:///` urls).